# everything even which is not listed is scrolling with recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, imageview

I used recyclerView for horizontal image scroll. In adapter, I have mentioned implementing recyclerView only to the ImageView and TextView.

Then in XML, I added some additional ImageViews to make images of recycler view SHARED, DOWNLOADED.

BUT, all the additional imageView are also scrolling with the recycler view. I want to make them stay stable. It made me very frustrated.

please help me, I'm beginner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <!--These 2 imageView are not listed in recyclerView but is still scrolling with recycler view. -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_others_black"/>
```

I tried to add `include` in XML, but is crashes the app :(

Comment: please add the code and xml

Comment: @bugfreerammohan I added. please help me

Comment: @Rajana where's your recyclerview layout, and items layout

Comment: @ManojPerumarath in recyclerView layout i have given id and width is mathparent and height is wrapparent. I didnt understand about items(it might be of above) layout?

Answer (score 0):

try it use this sample

step 1 : add picasso library into build.gradel

[Picasso Link](https://github.com/square/picasso)

step 2 : build a model for keeping information

```
public class ImageSliderModel {

// you can create variable int or string path
private String image;
private String text;

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

step 3 : create recyclerview adapter

```
public class HorizontalImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

ArrayList<ImageSliderModel> imageSliderModels;

public HorizontalImageAdapter(ArrayList<ImageSliderModel> imageSliderModels) {
    this.imageSliderModels = imageSliderModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ImageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your layout , parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(imageSliderModels.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageSliderModels.size();
}

class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //your custom layout imageview id
        //imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.your custom layout imageview id);

        //your custom layout textview id
        //textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.your custom layout textview id);

    }

    public void bind(ImageSliderModel model) {

        // Picasso is the best library for loading image
        // you can added this implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828' build.gradle file into tag dependencies and sync project and use
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage());

        textView.setText(model.getText());

    }
}

}
```

and the last step set this code into activity or view for creating

```
ArrayList<ImageSliderModel> sliderModels = new ArrayList<>();

    // create fake data
    // you can give date in server and set your model array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ImageSliderModel sliderModel = new ImageSliderModel();
        sliderModel.setImage("image path");
        sliderModel.setText("text");
        sliderModels.add(sliderModel);
    }

    // create adapter for recyclerview
    HorizontalImageAdapter imageAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(sliderModels);

    //config recyclerview for showing rows horizontal and casting
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recy);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //set adapter in recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: where I can add my images from raw?

Answer (score 0):

By experimenting many times, I got a solution.

You can put any view that you want to show aside `recyclerView` in the layout where `recyclerView` is introduced. :)